# Cannot Install Npx

Tags: node.js, npx

I am getting a strange error when trying to install npx. I have node, but it says I don't.

```
➜  Desktop brew install npm
Warning: node 14.4.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 14.4.0, run `brew reinstall node`
➜  Desktop npm install -g npx
zsh: command not found: npm
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

npx is pre-bundled with npm .no need to install npx. if u want to start a new react project (I presume)give npx create-react-app project name given that you installed the latest node version.